# Why is the number of labelled 3-colored graphs and 3-colorable graphs on n labelled nodes different?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Why are sequences [A191371](https://oeis.org/A191371) and
[A084279](https://oeis.org/A084279) different ?

Where,

A191371: Number of simple labeled graphs with (at most) 3-colored nodes such that no edge connects two nodes of the same color.

A084279:Number of labeled 3-colorable (i.e., chromatic number <= 3) graphs on n nodes.

I am sure it is not the case that A084279 is not simple, as the mathworld links for explaining it points to examples fo simple graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best intuition:

The first sequence refers to the number of *colored* graphs whereas the second sequence refers to the number of *colorable* graphs. The first sequence accounts for the number of ways to color a graph whereas the second one doesn't.

For example, there are two labeled 3-colorable graphs on 2 vertices, one where they are connected and the other where they are not. So the second sequence counts it as 2. For the connected case, there are 6 ways to color the connected case and 9 ways to color the disconnected case, so the first sequence counts it as 15.